# Using error handling within a formula which has multiple parts

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-formula

I'm trying to implement error handling as part of the following formula, to account for cells in each range which simply don't have a value and return a "#NUM!" error:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(R2:T2,U2:W2)/SUM(R2:T2)}
```

So far I've had some luck using IF and ISNUMBER combined (as shown below) when splitting up the main formula above, but I'm struggling when it comes to implementing it for each section/cell range. My attempt:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(R3:T3),R3:T3))}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why the **{** and **}** ? That first one doesn't need CSE.

Comment: Provide 6 values (R2:W2) that work. Provide another 6 values (R3:W3) that don't work. Provide the expected result and the returned error code for the one that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original formula, without error handling, can be entered normally. It doesn't need Ctl+Shift+Enter. Nor can it produce a #NUM error because both the SUM() and SUMPRODUCT() functions interpret non-numeric values as zero. Therefore, if you get a #NUM error that error would be created by formulas in the range R2:W2. You should introduce error handling there, not in the formula we are looking at here.

The formula here - that is your first, original formula - will produce a Division by Zero error if SUM(R2:T2) equals zero. `=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(R2:T2,U2:W2)/SUM(R2:T2),0)` would return zero in case of such an error. You can modify the formula to something like `=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(R2:T2,U2:W2)/SUM(R2:T2),"ERROR")` if you prefer.

This kind of error handler would take effect also if an unhandled error is inherited from R2:W2. My recommendation is to handle errors where they occur but if you wish for a more specific error handler in the formula we are looking at here, the formula below would let imported #NUM errors pass and only handle #DIV BY ZERO errors produced by this formula.
`=SUMPRODUCT(R3:T3,U3:W3)/IF(SUM(R3:T3),SUM(R3:T3),1)`
This formula divides the result of the SUMPRODUCT() function by 1 if SUM(R3:T3) equals zero. This returns a result from the formula of 0 because the SUMPRODUCT part would return zero  (unless it inherits a #NUM error).

Comment: Thank you Variatus, I was looking at this the wrong way. I added IFERROR to the reference cells to return a 0 in case of any blanks, and now the resulting SUMPRODUCT/SUM formula returns the expected output.